# androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView not compatible with API < 26

Tags: android, android-support-library, compatibility, androidx

I have a strange problem after migrating our project to androidx. We use a custom view that extends from androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView. However, the app crashes on device with API < 26 with the following stack trace ( cut to only the relevant part ):

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.view.textclassifier.TextClassifier
    at libcore.reflect.InternalNames.getClass(InternalNames.java:55)
    at java.lang.Class.getDexCacheType(Class.java:2551)
    at java.lang.reflect.AbstractMethod.getParameterTypes(AbstractMethod.java:169)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.getParameterTypes(Method.java:193)
    at org.greenrobot.eventbus.SubscriberMethodFinder.findUsingReflectionInSingleClass(SubscriberMethodFinder.java:163)
    at org.greenrobot.eventbus.SubscriberMethodFinder.findUsingInfo(SubscriberMethodFinder.java:88)
    at org.greenrobot.eventbus.SubscriberMethodFinder.findSubscriberMethods(SubscriberMethodFinder.java:64)
    at org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus.register(EventBus.java:140)
    at com.chrono24.mobile.controls.LocalizedTextView.onAttachedToWindow(LocalizedTextView.kt:65)
```

Now, as I see the android.view.textclassifier.TextClassifier is added with API 26, which would explain why the class is missing. If I change the AppCompatTextView to just plain old TextView, the app starts again without crashing. Any idea why is this happening and how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem disappeared when I downgraded the androidx libs from alpha to stable.

Comment: It looks like the problem occurs when the custom view tries to register itself with the greenrobot EventBus.

Answer (score 0):

you just have to make sure you are not using custom fonts or .ttf files
if you are using then Convert your .ttf file to .otf it will work fine for android 10
it is a known issue with android 10 right now.